# Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..2: 3

Tags: flutter, dart

i'm getting this error 'Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..2: 3' trying to display the existing answer as a hint text in the textfield

```
TextField(
                    onChanged: (String ansr) {
                      answers[question] = ansr;
                    },
                    onSubmitted: (String ansr) {
                      _write(answers);
                    },
                    controller: myController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 128, 124, 124),
                        ),
                      ),
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 128, 124, 124),
                        ),
                      ),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 128, 124, 124),
                        ),
                      ),
                      hintText: data[index].answer.isEmpty ? "Write something" :  data[index].answer
                    ),
                  ),
```

here's the whole code: https://pastecode.io/s/z55k699y

Comment: here you list getting  3 length .and the index is 0,1,2. the problem you supplaying index 3 in here.so that reason showing 0..2: 3 inclusive range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be happening because the list which you are using to show the
existing answer. does not have the same length as length of qst map which you are using for ListView.builder.

```
 List<Data> data = [];
```

and in the hintText you are checking if data[index].answer.isEmpty , when the element does not even exist. Try creating same length of list and map.

Hope this works!

Answer (score 0):

You might be using ListView.builder without specifying itemCount parameter.

Comment: i am providing the `itemCount: qst.keys.length,`

Comment: please share code with parent widget which you are using to fetch qst

Comment: here: https://pastecode.io/s/z55k699y